# Disabling mouse-wheel window-shading in XFce?

Tags: xfce, mouse

If I place the mouse over the titlebar of a window, and roll the mouse-wheel, the window will become shaded. Is there any way to disable this feature?

Comment: Are you running Compiz? Is [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=116179) relevant?

Comment: In Xfce 4.10, the `mousewheel_rollup` property is set to `false` already. This means, rolling the mouse wheel over the title bar of a window does not shade the window by default. No action is required.

Comment: @user125388 for me it was not false by default, but thanks for the hint on the correct property to search for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

better format: (sry 4 double answer)

1. go to settings> setting editor
2. click on xfwm4 in 'chanel side bar
3. click on general to display tree list and find one called 'mouesewheel_rollup'
4. click on to highlight and click edit icon at top of window
5. its a Bool so all you need to do is uncheck enable box.
6. save

from: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=110&t=101468

Comment: I wanted the opposite but these instructions work also to do the opposite. Thanks

Comment: "Channel", not "chanel"  _sheesh_

Answer (score -1):

In 4.14, I had to go bac a decade to this old solution:

> `xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/mousewheel_rollup -s false`

Source: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=23592#p23592